# How to get origin of this url "https://sso.domainname.com/adfs/services/trust/mex"?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am getting an error message when trying to connect to Dynamics 365 environment from my application.

Exception Message : Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://adfs.domainname.com/adfs/services/trust/mex'.

What i am trying to find out is the physical appearance this url(https://adfs.domainname.com/adfs/services/trust/mex) in Azure ADFS. I am a beginner in Azure.

Does this url exists in azure or is it something like a datapoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoint you are looking at is not an Azure endpoint. It is an ADFS endpoint and Azure uses it in scenarios, where your custom domain is federated with your on-premise ADFS server for authentication.

Let's assume you have a domain called carnival.com verified in Azure and you have users who are synchronized from your on-premise AD, user1@carnival.com, user2@carnival.com etc. Now if you federate carnival.com with your ADFS in the on-premise environment, then Azure AD will redirect the users to ADFS endpoints when authentication is required.

It looks like the information provided while configuring the ADFS is wither wrong or your ADFS is currently not reachable. Ideally when you navigate to that endpoint, it should display an XML as shown in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/troubleshooting/ad-fs-tshoot-endpoints).

Try checking if the authentication to Azure AD is working for the domain in question and check with your ADFS team to troubleshoot this further.